# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443 on ubuntu

Tags: curl, openssl, libcurl, ubuntu-18.04, minikube

I've been trying to install minikube on my Ubuntu machine as per this [post](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/).

But whenever I try to run...

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
  && chmod +x minikube
```

... I got following error.

> OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to storage.googleapis.com:443

For more details please check attached screenshot.
[image]

OS Version:**Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**

Curl Version:  **curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)**

OpenSSL Version: **OpenSSL/1.1.1**

*So far I've tried to run this command by downgrading curl to 7.33, upgrading to 7.68 and even reinstalled my OS and tried this command but its always shows me same error. I've been scratching my head to solve this problem for last 2 night any suggestion or solution would be much appreciated.*

Comment: Can you add verbose output of curl command? You can achieve this by adding `-v` parameter (`curl -v ...`)